# ASP.NET Core app crashing

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm running an ASP.NET Core app on kestrel in a docker container on AWS. When first running the container everything works well. Some time later (minutes) the site will stop working. At this point my docker container is no longer running.

I suspect that the resulting process of `dotnet MyWebsite.dll` crashes which causes the container to stop running as well.

I have inspected the container logs using `docker-compose logs` but see no exceptions or errors at all.

Does Kestrel have its own log files somewhere that I could inspect? Anything else I could take a look at to try and get this problem resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the console logs of your application using the command

```
docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
```

where CONTAINER is the name of your docker container.
Refer to docker logs [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

Hopefully, you will be able to see the exception which caused your application to crash/exit.